Calculate the Hilbert transform of the function $f(t)=(1+t^2)^{-1}$
I have the Hilbert transform of a function $f$ defined as
\begin{equation*}
H(f)(s)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(t)}{s-t}dt, \, \, \, s\in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
and I want to calculate the Hilbert transform of the function $f=(1+t^2)^{-1}$.
This is what I have done:
\begin{equation*}
F(w)=\mathfrak{F} \left( \frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)= \pi e^{-\lvert w \rvert}
\end{equation*}
with $\mathfrak{F}$ the Fourier transform of $f$.
\begin{equation*}
\mathfrak{F}(H(f))=i sgn(w)F(w)=isgn(w)\pi e^{-\lvert w \rvert} \Rightarrow \mathfrak{F}^{-1}\mathfrak{F}(Hf) = \mathfrak{F}^{-1}(isgn(w)\pi e^{-\lvert w \rvert}) = \mathfrak{F}^{-1}(isgn(w))\mathfrak{F}^{-1}(\pi e^{-\lvert w \rvert})= \mathfrak{F}^{-1}\left(\mathfrak{F}\left(\frac{1}{\pi t}\right)\right)\cdot \left( \frac{1}{1+t^2}\right) = \frac{1}{\pi t (1+t^2)}=H(f)
\end{equation*}
Is that correct?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

The Wikipedia definition of the Hilbert transform is as the principal value of the integral you gave, which shouldn't be omitted. Moreover, said page includes a table of such transforms and indicates a wholly different result than the one you propose.

Let $f(t)=\frac1{1+t^2}$. We can write $f$ as the partial fraction expansion
$$f(t)=\frac1{s^2+1}\left(\frac{s}{x^2+1}+\frac{x}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x-s}\right)$$
Then, the Hilbert transform of $f$ is given by
$$\begin{align}
H\{f\}(s)&=\frac1\pi\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(s-t)(1+t^2)}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac1\pi\frac1{s^2+1}\left(\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{s}{x^2+1}\,dx+\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{x^2+1}\,dx-\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{x-s}\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\frac1\pi \frac1{s^2+1}\left(\pi s+0-0\right)\\\\
&=\frac{s}{s^2+1}
\end{align}$$
And we are done!
